# Присоединить вызов метода

Tags: javascript

Есть класс Test с методом ShowMessage. 
Я ему могу присвоить новый метод Message. 
Но как мне добавить еще один вызов к существующему? Хочу присоединить JoinMessage.
Должно при вызове ShowMessage отобразится сообщение Test message а затем Join message

```
function Test() {
    this.ShowMessage = function() {
        // default method
    };
}

function Message() {
    alert("Test message");
}

function JoinMessage() {
    alert("Join message");
}

var t = new Test();
t.ShowMessage = Message; // ОК
t.ShowMessage += JoinMessage; // FAIL
t.ShowMessage();
```

Comment: Не спец по js, но что-то подобное должно прокатить:

    var savedShowMessage = t.ShowMessage;
    t.ShowMessage = function()
    {
        savedShowMessage.apply(this);
        JoinMessage.apply(this);
    };

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function Test() {
    this.methods = [];
    this.ShowMessage = function() {
        for(var i = 0; i < this.methods.length; i++) {
            this.methods[i]();
        }
    };
    this.addMethod = function ( method ) {
        this.methods.push(method);
    };
}

function Message() {
    alert("Test message");
}

function JoinMessage() {
    alert("Join message");
}

var t = new Test();
t.addMethod( Message );
t.addMethod( JoinMessage );
t.ShowMessage();

// можно и через прототипы подсластить и вызовы через apply сделать
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто запихнем их в анонимную функцию в нужном порядке:

```
var t = new Test();
t.ShowMessage = function() {
    Message();
    JoinMessage();
};
t.ShowMessage();
```